# NativeScript Angular .ics file export

Tags: nativescript, icalendar, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I would like to add a .ics export to my NativeScript Angular app. I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ics to create a string containing the content of a .ics file. The idea is, that this .ics is opened by the default calendar app of the smartphone and the user may store the event in his calendar.
Is there a way to implement this in NativeScript?

Thank you and have a nice day,

Rolandos